# Can't select first two child elements with :nth-child(-n+2)

Tags: html, css

I'm new to nth-child. Before I would just add an extra class to the element, but now I want to keep the work in the css. I'm trying to grab the first two divs(change some props) and then last two divs(change some different props) within the .content div. I only want to start accessing this from a media query of a max-width: 768px. From the tutorial I watched my syntax looks right(.services .content:nth-child(-n+2)), I don't know why it isn't working?

https://jsfiddle.net/xjq4rf25/

```
    <section class="services" id="services">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Services</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <ul class="skills">
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Flatwork</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Paving</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Driveways</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Sidewalks</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="move">
        <ul class="skills">
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Foundations</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Flooring</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Seismic Retrofit</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Other Concrete Concerns</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <ul class="skills">
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Commercial</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Residential</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Decks and Patios</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Kitchen Flooring</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <ul class="skills">
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Demolition</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Grading/Clean up</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Slab Repair</p></li>
          <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Curb Repair</p></li>               
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: so you want to affect ONLY the first two and last two?

Comment: Right now just the first two. Once I've changed the properties I wanted then I'll do the last two, with(n+3). As the tutorial suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.services .content>div:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .services .content>div:nth-child(-n+2) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qhp1uneb/

Comment: 1.) I don't understand though? Isn't `.services .content > div:nth-child` accessing the children within those divs? Since it is the divs I want to affect don't I need to put nth-child on their parent element?

Comment: 2.) When I do `.services .content:nth-child(-n+2)` however the div.content is the element that gets styled? why is this?

Comment: @Alfred :nth-child is applied to the selector on which it is associated. So, here it is being applied on div and content in 1 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be this one:

```
.services .content div:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background-color:red;
}

.services .content div:nth-child(n+3) {
  background-color:blue;
}
```